# How to clear cookies in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, http-headers, ionic-framework, session-cookies, httpcookie

i am using a web service having basic authentication i.e. below code shows how i calling the web service

```
var url='http:url.com/;
      $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + Base64.encode(Username + ':' + password);
      $http({method: 'GET', url: url}).
          success(function(data) {
              if(data=='' || data==null || data=='undefined'){
                  var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                      title: 'Info!',
                      template: 'Invalid Password, or no user found with this Email Address'
                  });
                  alertPopup.then(function(res) {
                      console.log('Invalid Password, or no user found with this Email Address ');
                  });
                  return false;
              }
              else{
                  var favoriteCookie = $cookies['JSESSIONID'];

                  window.localStorage['data'] = JSON.stringify(data);
                  //console.log("LOGIvar: " + data+ " - PW: " + password);
                  console.log(data);
                  $state.go('app.tasklists');
                  return false;
              }
          }).
```

i am getting the correct response and all working fine.
But when i logout the app i am using the below code

```
 $cookieStore.remove('JSESSIONID');
  $cookieStore.remove('JSESSIONIDSSO');
  $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']='undefind';
  $scope.modal.show();
  $state.go('login',{}, {reload: true});
```

the real problem is when i logedout then try to logged in with incorrect password it getting logged in web service retuning the previous user details.how can i fix this one thanks in advance?

Comment: are you sure this is a cookie topic since you are storing all your data in the localStorage?

Comment: Offtopic: you should rethink your if statement: `if(data=='' || data==null || data=='undefined'){...`

Comment: Thanks,while trying in browser if removed cookies and header then it ask re authentication and also i clearing in my ios native application then it is working fine.and the second one sure i will change that for  now there is no status returning thats why i put like this

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer your question:

remove cookies and header, then it asks for re-authentication and also clear native application then it is working fine

Comment: Thanks,How to clear native application? sorry for disturbing you.    is there any wrong in the below method for deleting cookies $cookieStore.remove('JSESSIONID');
  $cookieStore.remove('JSESSIONIDSSO');
  $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']='undefind';
  $scope.modal.show();
  $state.go('login',{}, {reload: true});